# organizing columns in excel into standard format

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I have data in a excel spreadsheet in a regular pattern that needs to be organized in a format friendly to statistical analysis.

Here is the format:

```
        Clinton 29.30%  22
        Edwards 38.70%  29
        Obama   32.00%  24    

Adair


        Clinton 36.00%  22
        Edwards 38.00%  29
        Obama   14.00%  24
        Other   12.00%  10    

Adams
```

I'd like it in a standard matrix format:

```
county candidate percent absolute
Adair  clinton   29%    22
Adair  obama     32%    24
```

...

```
Adams   clinton   36%
Adams   obama ....
```

What is the best way to do this in excel or google docs? Apologies if this is some kind of beginner question. I tried searching the forum, but couldn't find what this kind of procedure is called.

Comment: Is this an `Microsoft-Excel` question or a `Google-Spreadsheet` question? The two platforms differ in the method to accomplish what you are looking for and it would be a waste of time to pursue one when you actually wanted the other.

Comment: I'd be happy with a solution from either! i have access to both

Comment: is there a better way to ask this question? should i only have asked for one?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement use "data validation" option which can be see by right clicking a cell in Google sheet. Select the whole column and set data validations. Also you can format column using format toolbar option where you can auto set the percentage conversions.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to use data validation to solve this problem. can you give me more detail?